# Copy the content of a CD file with executables to your hard-drive

Tags: copy-paste, compact-disc

I have a CD with medical results. The cd has two `exe` files. One is used to launch and visualize the content. The second is used to visualize some images and maybe is called from the other. The images are DICOM. When the CD is inserted the exe files run properly.

I tried first to copy the content of the CD in a folder and I also created an iso image. I then opened both of them and tried to execute them. None of the copied exe files executed.

So my question is: how to copy the content of a CD containing the executables to your HD so that the exe files execute as when launched from the CD? Did anyone else experienced the same?

Comment: How did you create the ISO image? How did you mount it to run the software? What Windows version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1. create a new folder medical results,
2. insert the original cd
3. with files explorer right clic on your cd drive `open in a new windows`
4. select all the files and copy them  ( ctrl+a and ctrl+c )
5. now go in the new folder medical result right clic past or ctrl+v

now test if everything work in your new folder medical results

if not we may need to see the files in the cd call autorun.inf

Comment: well that is what I did. I can paste the autorun

Comment: do you know if you autoplay is enable ? if not https://www.howtogeek.com/236241/how-to-enable-disable-and-customize-autoplay-in-windows-10/

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to copy files inside CD but copy/paste the CD Reader Icon.

See the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]